# Custom Wordpress URL

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

Any ways I could show Custom Post Type's Content with such URL?
E.g: (www.mydomain.com/view-promotion/christmas-promotion)

- view-promotion is page name
- christmas-promotion is the custom post type's post name

Currently this URL (www.mydomain.com/view-promotion/christmas-promotion) is automatically changed to (www.mydomain.com/promotion/christmas-promotion) where (promotion) is the post_type.

I am trying to have the view-promotion (Page Template) to show content by using custom post type name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a slug, when you are registering the post type with [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). You can add this argument like this

```
$labels = array(
    //... add the labels as you need
   )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    //add other options as you need
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'view-promotion')
);

register_post_type( 'promotion', $args );
```

}

**EDIT:**

You need some other identifier to differentiate between the page and your custom post type. Otherwise Wordpress won't be able to know whether you mean the `view-promotion` page or the custom post type.

Even something like this will work

```
...
'rewrite' => 'view-promotion/a',
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help. However, I am trying to have the view-promotion page to use the Page Template. Changing the slug would only still have wordpress to use custom post type template.

Comment: @Noobie do you mean that `view-promotion` is a page that you have created?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to have view-promotion page to pull content by using custom post name.

Comment: @Noobie see my edit.

Comment: thanks a bunch. It works when I set it to (view-promotion/).
May I ask why putting it this way works?